# Move usernames to the left of comments?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Is it possible to place usernames on the left side of the comments? That way it would feel like a conversation.

Furthermore, you wouldn't have to skip to the end of the comment to see who's speaking.  It feels a bit unnatural to scan at the end of a comment to verify who's asking and who's answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I responded to a similar request at [Authors should be identified at top of post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106946/authors-should-be-identified-at-top-of-post/106947#106947), which proposed the same change for questions and answers.  That post, the question, and the comments gives additional reasoning for and against the proposal.

To summarize, on Stack Exchange, the *content* is more important than the  *creator*.  This is true both in comments and in questions/answers.

Answer (score 4):

Comments shouldn't be used for discussions (it is a bit different on meta tho).

Comment: What distinguishes a discussion (inappropriate use of comment) from a real comment?

Answer (score 4):

One problem I can see with making comments look more like an instant message stream is that people will treat it like one, and I don't think that's really what we want.